# What effects does Ancestry have on a Dragonborn?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dragonborn

During character creation, Dragonborn characters can choose an "Ancestry". This mainly determines the colour of their scales, and the breath weapon they get.

Does Ancestry affect anything else? I haven't been able to find anything special in the Player's Handbook and the only benefits Dragonborn are given come from Race, not Ancestry (that I can find).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A dragonborn's draconic ancestry only affects the type of the characters breath weapon and their resistances, by RAW. Dragonborn are described (PH p. 32) as, "...generations of interbreeding have created a more uniform appearance...", so we know that not every dragonborn's ancestry is immediately apparent.

However the dragonborn entry (PH p. 32) does talk about SOME dragon born clans where, "the blood of a particular type of dragon runs very strong...", and that members of those clans more closely resemble their draconic ancestors. Whether a given character would be from such a clan, and what that would mean, is left as a discussion between the player and the DM.